# Getting the context in a BrowseSupportFragment

Tags: android

I migrated recently from `BrowseFragment` to `BrowseSupportFragment` in Kotlin for an Android TV app.

In the `onActivityCreated` I set some properties which rely on getting the color. To get the colors I use:

```
ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.fastlane_background);
```

The issue here is that context is nullable and `getColor` doesn't accept that.

Every time I need the context, do I need to do something like this:

```
val ctx = context ?: return
ContextCompat.getColor(ctx, R.color.fastlane_background);
```

Is this the recommended solution, are there better ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Use `requireContext()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment.html#requirecontext) to get a non-`null` `Context` associated with your `Fragment`.